# (GET) API Request Failed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch API data from antares (IoT Platform) using native javascript, here's the code

```js
var url = 'https://platform.antares.id:8443/~/antares-cse/antares-id/SuhuPagarsih/Temperature/la';
var opt = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'X-M2M-Origin': 'bdc2996719c6ac07:8cbb60e9c5997e74',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;ty=4',
        'Accept':'application/json',
    },
}

fetch(url, opt)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Here's the result

[image: Result Image]

as you can see, it's failed. Most of the time I see the error reason is forbidden. But when I try using node js and snippet code from postman. I get a good result (200 OK) Here's the code if you need to compare (I guess it's all the same)

```js
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "platform.antares.id",
  "port": "8443",
  "path": "/~/antares-cse/antares-id/SuhuPagarsih/Temperature/la",
  "headers": {
    "x-m2m-origin": "bdc2996719c6ac07:8cbb60e9c5997e74",
    "content-type": "application/json;ty=3",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "ff6cbe83-97ac-6ed5-aaec-e2bafaf44002"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

And here's the result

[image: Result Image]

My questions is, what seems to be the problem? what's the difference between making API request from native javascript and node js? and how can I resolve this problem?
Or maybe is there anyway around this issues? My goal is only to show the data from API to HTML/Web Page

Thank you!

Comment: Your request is getting blocked by the browser due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: it could have something to do with `cors` policy

Comment: I also already try adding mode: 'no-cors' 
and it'll flag forbidden error (as I mention), rather than cors error

Comment: It's solved guys, this is happen because the endpoint of the API is a backend domain (url:8443). Therefore, any request that comes from frontend are rejected by CORS Policy